# returning address or local variable or temporary C++ warning

Tags: c++, warnings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ warning: address of local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862494/c-warning-address-of-local-variable)

Hi,
When i write this code:

```
//Returns the transpose matrix of this one
SparseMatrix& SparseMatrix::transpose()const{
    vector<Element> result;
    size_t i;
    for(i=0;i<_matrix.size();++i){
        result.push_back(Element(_matrix.at(i)._col, _matrix.at(i)._row, _matrix.at(i)._val));
    }

    return SparseMatrix(numCol,numRow,result);
}
```

I get the warning "returning address or local variable or temporary". The last line calls the SparseMatrix constructor. I don't understand what's wrong with this code, and how can i fix it so i can return a SparseMatrix object as i want.

Answer (score 17):

You're returning a reference, not an actual object - note the `&` here:

```
SparseMatrix& SparseMatrix::transpose()const{
```

If you want to return the actual object, remove that `&`.

The last line does indeed call the constructor, but it doesn't return the resulting object.  That object immediately gets destroyed, and an invalid reference to it gets returned.

Comment: +1 the "&" is useless (in fact erroneous) here!

Comment: thanks! I haven't noticed i've declared it as a ref return value.

Answer (score 13):

In C++, local variables are 'automatically' destructed when going out of scope.  Your `return` statement will create a nameless, temporary variable of type `SparseMatrix` that will immediately go out of scope.  Hence, returning a reference to it doesn't make sense.

It may be easier to return by value: then a copy of the temporary will be returned.  The compiler can optimize that away (copy elision).

If you really want to pass an object out of a function, you should create it on the heap, using `new`:

```
SparseMatrix* SparseMatrix::transpose()const{

     //...
     return new SparseMatrix(...);
}
```

But then, you need to take care of the lifetime of the returned object yourself.

Comment: quick question, if you do that, would it be recommend that you use `[[no discard]]`?

Comment: No: `[[no discard]]` is meant to avoid ignoring errors.  (by the way, today I'll advice using `std::unique_ptr<SparseMatrix>`, avoiding raw pointers).

Answer (score 0):

The construct 'T()' creates a temporary of type 'T' which is basically not an Lvalue (but an Rvalue).

> $12.1/11 - "A functional notation type
> conversion (5.2.3) can be used to
> create new objects of its type. [
> Note: The syntax looks like an
> explicit call of the constructor.
>
> 12 An object created in this way is unnamed. [ Note: 12.2 describes the lifetime of >temporary objects. —end
> note ] [ Note: explicit constructor calls do not yield lvalues, see 3.10. —end note ]
> The lifetime of this temporary is the end of the full expression i.e. the ending semicolon after the expression.
>
> $12.2/3 - "Temporary objects are
> destroyed as the last step in
> evaluating the full-expression (1.9)
> that (lexically) contains the point
> where they were created. This is true
> even if that evaluation ends in
> throwing an exception. The value
> computations and side effects of
> destroying a temporary object are
> associated only with the
> full-expression, not with any specific
> subexpression."
>
> $12.2/5- 'The lifetime of a temporary
> bound to the returned value in a
> function return statement (6.6.3) is
> not extended; the temporary is
> destroyed at the end of the
> full-expression in the return
> statement."

Therefore your function tries to return a reference to a memory location whose storage duration is already over and the object has been destroyed.

Therefore a warning. Note that this situation is not required to be explicitly diagnosed by the Standard and hence a warning.