# Boost Thread dies before job finished

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, boost-thread

I am using the boost library to implement a socket communication. In respect to my main application, a connection handler should be launched who deals with all incoming requests.

Therefore I have encapsulated the whole server handler into the class server. When the server object is created it should launch the server.

However this way the thread dies with the execution end of the constructor code. I guess I don't get how boost / posix threads work. I come from a Java background.

```
server::server(int port) {

try {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp_server server(io_service, port);
    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
} catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Post the definition of the tcp_server class. It's also not obvious to me why you need a separate thread to run the io_service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `io_service` needs to be primed with some `io_service::work` to do, either explicitly or from your `tcp_server` object. Otherwise `io_service::run`() will return control immediately. Study the [asio examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html), this concept is important to understand.

> The work class is used to inform the
> io_service when work starts and
> finishes. This ensures that the
> io_service object's run() function
> will not exit while work is underway,
> and that it does exit when there is no
> unfinished work remaining.
>
> The work class is copy-constructible
> so that it may be used as a data
> member in a handler class. It is not
> assignable.

I suspect your code is a contrived example, it likely does not need a thread to run the io_service. The main thread will do just fine.

Answer (score 5):

You are constructing a local variable `io_service`, which you pass to the worker function of your new thread. When the variable goes out of scope (constructor exits), `io_service` is destroyed and can no longer be accessed.

However, your thread's worker function does not know this and presumably tries to access the remains of that object again. Ugliness ensues.

The error does not have to do with threads but is an instance of a common type of error called "[returning the address of a local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862494/c-warning-address-of-local-variable)" (even though you are not actually returning it here, the mechanism is the same).

The solution would be to extend the lifetime of the `io_service` object, either by taking manual control (`new`/`delete`) or by increasing it (e.g. making it a class member on `server` instead of a local inside the constructor).

You also seem to have a problem with the `server` variable, which is also a local and will be destroyed as soon as the constructor exists. Since you aren't actually using it at all this is not a problem with the code you posted, but anyway it's an indication that you are doing something suspicious.

Comment: Thanks, I see that I am missing some very essentials here.